# Mangled Movie Titles

Tags: wordplay, movies

I've taken a bunch of movies and done...*something* to each of their titles.  In some instances, I've changed a single letter in one of the words.  In others, I've added a letter to make one of the words into a new word.  In still others, I've removed a letter from one of the words.  In each case, my alteration has given me a new movie, for which I've written a one line synopsis.  Can you work out what the original movies were?

*Example:  A group of dinosaurs discover electricity - JURASSIC SPARK.*

1) The heartrending tale of a family of adorable puppies who've forgotten how to bark.

2) Gordon Ramsay, Marco Pierre White, and Heston Blumenthal learn the hard way that crime doesn't pay.

3) A famous jeweler travels to the north of England to find his brother's killer.

4) In the jungles of Vietnam, an Aberdeen Angus threatens to destroy the world!

5) A cabbie talks nonsense at you for two hours.

6) The story of the secret life of a Boris Johnson action figure.

7) In a post apocalyptic waste land, an Australian lawman adopts a very bad tempered cat.

8) A father looks for his son at a My Chemical Romance concert.

9) A maverick cop foils a gang of terrorists using his secret weapon - pastries!

10) Set in the weeks after D-Day, a squadron tracks down a young soldier with a regulation defying moustache.

Comment: Haha! Love it! I'm 8/10 - just stuck on 2 and 5...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1) The heartrending tale of a family of adorable puppies who've forgotten how to bark.

> The Silence of the Labs (The Silence of the Lambs)

2) Gordon Ramsay, Marco Pierre White, and Heston Blumenthal learn the hard way that crime doesn't pay.

> With the hint from @Nellington and the contribution from @LannyStrack - this could be Meal (or Meat) Streets for Mean Streets. Or possibly the Color of Honey :) I was trying to work Michelin in there somewhere, but that was too much to ask!

3) A famous jeweler travels to the north of England to find his brother's killer.

> Get Cartier (Get Carter)

4) In the jungles of Vietnam, an Aberdeen Angus threatens to destroy the world!

> Apocalypse Cow (Apocalypse Now)

5) A cabbie talks nonsense at you for two hours.

> Taxi Drivel (Taxi Driver) - Thanks to @stiv for the nudge (originally had Drivler, to mean One Who Drivels, but the spelling wasn't adding up)

6) The story of the secret life of a Boris Johnson action figure.

> Tory Story (Toy Story)

7) In a post apocalyptic waste land, an Australian lawman adopts a very bad tempered cat.

> Mad Manx (Mad Max) - thanks to @DarrelHoffman. Previously I had Mad Max - Furry Road (Mad Max - Fury Road)

8) A father looks for his son at a My Chemical Romance concert.

> Finding Emo (Finding Nemo)

9) A maverick cop foils a gang of terrorists using his secret weapon - pastries!

> Pie Hard (Die Hard)

10) Set in the weeks after D-Day, a squadron tracks down a young soldier with a regulation defying moustache.

> Shaving Private Ryan (Saving Private Ryan)

I really like this, very clever.

Comment: Nice work Johnson! A little nudge on 5 - you've got it in essence but I'm pretty sure you just want rot13(Gnkv QEVIRY)!

Comment: Ahaha, thanks @Stiv - yep that makes sense

Comment: Good work Johnson, quick hint for 2: (rot13: fpbefrfr)

Comment: I think that 2 might be (answer spoiler) rot14-to-view/  yqmf efdqqfe

Comment: Thanks Nellington - great puzzle :). I've edited number 2 now - I had reached a similar answer @LannyStrack, I think either would work

Comment: Number 7 is surely rot13(Znq Znak).

Comment: Ahah - that does sound a bit better than what I had @DarrelHoffman - thanks, will update

Answer (score 0):

5)

> Mad Manx (most people don't realize that its an island with a Gaelic speaking people and think its just a cat)

Comment: Haha. Try to add more detail to your answer!

Comment: I already said that in the comments to Johnson's answer - also it's #7, not #5.